# Error in vpPathFromVector(names) : A viewport path must contain at least one viewport name

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

[Cross posted on Google groups of ggplot](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/e4_wYbwq1cY):

The below reproducible example of `gglocator`(ggplot2):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
df <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)
qplot(xvar, yvar, data = df) + annotate(geom = 'point', x = 3, y = 6)
gglocator(4)
```

works perfectly fine on `openSUSE 11.4 (64 bit)` with `sessionInfo()` as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C            
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C               
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C          
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C     

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base   

other attached packages:
[1] ggmap_2.1     ggplot2_0.9.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.15.1     
 [5] labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-18        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3     
 [9] plyr_1.7.1         png_0.1-4          proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5
[13] reshape2_1.2.1     RgoogleMaps_1.2.0  rjson_0.2.8        scales_0.2.1    
[17] stringr_0.6
```

The same code throws the error (shown in title) when run on `Windows Vista` with `sessionInfo()` as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252  
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

---

**The `ggplot2` version on `Windows` is `0.9.2`, and on `Linux` it is `0.9.1`.**

Is this a known bug, or am I missing a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem, on windows.

In fact ìn the code of `gglocator`

```
 x <- x[grep("panel-", grid.ls(print = message)[[1]])]
```

The grep don't find any grob which contain 'panel-'.

When I remove the -

```
x[grep("panel", grid.ls(print = message)[[1]])]
[1] "panel.3-4-3-4"                    "panel.background.rect.5210"       "panel.grid.minor.y.polyline.5212" "panel.grid.minor.x.polyline.5214"
[5] "panel.grid.major.y.polyline.5216" "panel.grid.major.x.polyline.5218" "panel.border.zeroGrob.5207"
```

For me no reason that this works on linux.

Comment: `For me no reason that this works on linux.` My `ggplot2` version on Linux is different than on Windows.

Comment: @AnishaKaul 'this' means this code if I run it under linux. The problem is  in ggmap not ggplot2.